# Start and Close single Activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver

In my application i have one broadcast receiver of `POWER CABLE PLUG` and `UNPLUG`.

while `POWER CABLE PLUG` then service start and that service will start activity and when `POWER CABLE UNPLUG` then that service will stop and also opened activity should closed.

i have already start activity successfully but it can't close.

if you have any solution then please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to directly kill an activity by calling a static method in that activity:

```
Activity A should have a variable

static ActivityA activityA;
```

In onCreate state:

```
activityA = this;
```

and add this method:

```
public static ActivityA getInstance(){
    return   activityA;
 }
```

In activity B, call the fuction getInstance()

```
ActivityA.getInstance().finish();
```